# Raspberri Pi - MIDI to USB permission issue

Tags: python, permissions, raspberry-pi, usb, pi

I have been fighting this for a while now and wondering if I am on the right path...

I want to read MIDI data for my project via this USB to MIDI cable.

https://artproaudio.com/product/mconnec ... idi-cable/

Watching some tutorials and doing some reading and this is far I have gotten.

```py
import usb.core
import usb.backend.libusb1

VENDOR_ID = 0xfc02 
PRODUCT_ID = 0x0101 

device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)

if device is None:
    raise ValueError('ADU Device not found. Please ensure it is connected to the tablet.')
    sys.exit(1)

# Claim interface 0 - this interface provides IN and OUT endpoints to write to and read from
usb.util.claim_interface(device, 0)
```

with this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/new/usb_block.py", line 14, in <module>
usb.util.claim_interface(device, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/util.py", line 205, in claim_interface
device._ctx.managed_claim_interface(device, interface)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 159, in managed_claim_interface
self.managed_open()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 102, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 120, in managed_open
self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 786, in open_device
return _DeviceHandle(dev)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 643, in __init__
_check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

The error, `usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)` is the issue I cannot solve...

I have created a file in /etc/udev/rules.d
named, 50-usb-perms.rules
with the line, `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0xfc02", ATTR{idProduct}=="0x0101", MODE="0666"`
this did not solve the problem but, every thread of discusssion I can find seems to point in this direction.

Any Help?

TIA

Some additional info, dmesg returns;

```sh
[ 5810.425238] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 5822.756648] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 5822.895390] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=fc02, idProduct=0101, bcdDevice= 2.50
[ 5822.895407] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5822.895420] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB MIDI Interface
```